# I can get the token but CORS error display in secure route

Tags: php, laravel, cors, backend, single-page-application

I want to integrate Laravel with Angular. I can get the token becouse I ad this in cors.php

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', **'oauth/*'**],
```

But any another secure route doesn't work (display CORS error). I tryued use middleware

```
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
```

I registered that in Kernel.php and I added that in Kernel. Finally I added this middleware in my routing

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors', 'json.response']], function () {
    Route::get('/user', 'UserController@user')->middleware(['auth:api']);
    
});
```

But all the time I have a cors error. Any Idea how can I solve this?

How solve the problem with cors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [`fruitcake/laravel-cors`](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

In `config/app.php` -> `providers`

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Then in terminal

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

And finally in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // ...
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ],
];
```

---

Or

> **Upgrade to latest version of Laravel, which support cross-issue by framework itself**

Answer (score 0):

Try with default settings and then try to modify it if necessary.
No need to add other middleware, cause cors.php has default configuration which introduced by Laravel Team from Laravel 7.